# How do you embed XHTML into APT file when using Maven to generate a site?

Tags: java, xhtml, maven-2, web

I am using [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to generate a website for a Java project, which uses [APT "Almost Plain Text"](http://maven.apache.org/doxia/format.html) as a wiki like markup. Maven takes this and turns it into XHTML.

I already have a custom template/skin that I am using for the site, but the index page will have a couple of extra custom design elements that are beyond the capabilities of APT. So how can you add xhtml to the apt file so that it gets correctly embedded in the final output?

Thanks.

Comment: Should the XHTML be interpreted by the browser at the end or just printed in the page?

Comment: @Pascal - interpreted by the browser... Basically want to be able to "pass thru" XHTML right through to the final output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not appear possible at the current point in time. The work around was to define the index page as a resource "index.html" rather than a apt page "index.apt".

Comment: you can also create an index xdoc, where you can embed any xhtml into.